# Intercepting redirects in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, redirection

Is there a way in Chrome to intercept meta/301/302 redirects and decide whether or not to follow them?

I'm looking to do the same thing that [Django](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and Symfony 2 do to intercept requests:

[image: screenshot of redirect interception page with link to target URL]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a direct way to do this. There are some plugins that allow you to see what redirects are happening (for example [Redired-Path](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-path/aomidfkchockcldhbkggjokdkkebmdll?hl=en))but not to chose whether to follow them.

I would suggest looking at a local proxy to see if it can be made to do what you want. For example [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) might be coaxed into doing what you want.